# How to let qemu acquire memory dynamically?

Tags: qemu

My command to start qemu looks like this:

```bash
$ qemu-system-x86_64 \
    -name guest=win10 \
    -m 4830196K \
    -enable-kvm \
    -drive file=win10.img,format=raw,index=0,media=disk,if=virtio \
    ......
```

qemu takes up 4G of memory according to the parameters I gave, but the memory size used by the guest machine may only be 2G.

I want to specify the maximum memory available for a guest, how much memory the guest uses, and how much memory qemu takes.

what should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

QEMU does not support dynamic guest memory allocation in the way, say, Hyper-V does.

It does support an API (via the QEMU Object Model) and manual control of the *virtio-balloon* device, if present in the VM. Simply add `-device virtio-balloon` to the command line and you’re good to go. (There’s also a way with dynamically adding and removing virtual memory DIMMs, but I’m not familiar with that.)

You can use the QEMU Monitor console to issue the `balloon 1234` command, where `1234` is the target amount of RAM (in megabytes). You can also use `info balloon` to get the current allocation.

You can access QEMU Monitor using various methods, including sockets and [keyboard shortcuts](https://qemu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/system/keys.html).

*libvirt* encapsulates this feature (or perhaps the dynamic DIMM thing in newer versions), too. You can define a “current” and maximum memory size on VMs.